# "WifiService: Failed to load wifi driver."

Tags: android-emulator, android-wifi

I am using android emulator in windows 7. I get the following error in Lo cat when I try to enable wifi on the emulator: *WifiService: Failed to load wifi driver.*

How ever when I open browser in the emulator it shows up web pages properly. But I don't get any info when I use WifiManager in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator works as a software simulation of an actual device on a computer. It does not have the hardware to handle Wi-Fi and even telephony networks (3G etc.) for that matter.

The reason you are able to view web pages in the emulator browser is because it is able to connect via the internet connection in your computer.

And yes, WifiManager works fine when you test in a real device (that has Wi-Fi).